# Like operator returning false when string contains backtick

Tags: powershell, string-comparison, powershell-5.0

This might sound like a silly question but I do not understand why the presence of the backtick character fails a comparison with the Like operator.

For exemple :

```bsh
> 'a' -Like 'a'
True # Seems logical to me

> '`' -Like '`'
False # Why does this return false ?
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Since you're not using wildcards, you might as well use `-eq`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backtick (`` ` ``) works as an escape character for wildcard patterns in PowerShell, so the pattern `` ` `` is interpreted as just an empty string.

Escape it like so:

```bsh
'`' -like '``'
```

---

Beware that `` ` `` is *also* the escape character for expandable strings (ie. double-quoted string literals) in PowerShell, in which case you'd have to *double-escape* it:

`````
'`' -like "````"
`````

Comment: ```'`' -eq '``'``` returns `false`. Moreover, the `-like` operator behaves weirdly if combined with different string delimiters: both ```'`' -like "*`*"``` and ```'`' -like '*``*'``` return `true` unlike both ```'`' -like '*`*'``` and ```'`' -like "*``*"```.

Comment: `-eq` in the first example was a typo, fixed now. It doesn't behave weird, it behaves as designed. ```'*`*'``` would match _anything_ followed by a literal `*`. Expanding ```"*``*"``` results in the literal string ```*`*```, equivalent to the previous example

Comment: It should work within single quotes.  It works with -eq.  It seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Even in .net it doesn't work.

```
$pattern = [WildcardPattern]::new('`')
$pattern.IsMatch('`')

False
```